# An extra user on the list of moderators

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators

On the [list of moderators](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), one of the users is not like others. He is a former SE employee, not a moderator.

[image: mods]

Answer (score 5):

This is an artifact of the status of his accounts being changed from employee to normal user since he recently left SE.

For more information on this you can see this [Meta-SE Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277060/why-is-an-se-employee-suddenly-a-per-site-moderator)

Its been noted that this has happened on a few sites, I'm sure it will get resolved in due course.

Comment: ...as indeed it appears to have. The extra name is now gone.